# How to override a templates default option with javascript and css

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I´m using a template built upon bootstrap. It has a sidebar menu which can be toggled clicking on a button with the following code:

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="menu-toggler responsive-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
```

The menu's default state is uncollapsed. I know the following are very simple questions, but I have almost zero experience with javascript and css, and have not found a way to do it:

How can I call the previous code's functionality upon page load?

And what exactly is **href="javascript:;"** calling? How does it work?

Thank you.

Comment: `href="javascript:;" ` is essentially calling nothing. It's similar to `href="#"`. As for the rest, what is the 'previous code's' behavior? I'm not clear on what you're hoping to accomplish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a more accurate answer, please provide a link to the template.

> How can I call the previous code's functionality upon page load?

Try to simulate a click of the link on page load, with something like

```
 document.querySelector('.menu-toggler.responsive-toggler').click();
```

> And what exactly is href="javascript:;" calling? How does it work?

Apparently, it call javascript code from a link, but I have to say I have never this syntax before. In this particuliar case, it cancels the basic anchor functionnality to go to another webpage or id in the page.